# How to manage terraform for multiple repos

Tags: terraform

I have 2 repos for my project. A Static website and server. I want the website to be hosted by cloudfront and s3 and the server on elasticbeanstalk. I know these resources will need to know about a route53 resource at least to be under the same domain name for cors to work. Among other things such as vpcs and stuff.

So my question is how do I manage terraform with multiple repos.
I'm thinking I could have a seperate infrastructure repo that builds for all repos. 
I could also have them seperate and pass in the arns/names/ids as variables (annoying).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use terraform [remote_state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) for this. It lets you read the output variables from another terraform state file.

Lets assume you save your state files remotely on s3 and you have your `website.tfstate` and `server.tfstate` file. You could output your hosted zone ID of your route53 zone as `hosted_zone_id` in your `website.tfstate` and then reference that output variable directly in your server state terraform code.

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "website" {
  backend = "s3"

  config {
    bucket = "<website_state_bucket>"
    region = "<website_bucket_region>"
    key = "website.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "aws_route53_record" "www" {
  zone_id = "${data.terraform_remote_state.website.hosted_zone_id}"
  name    = "www.example.com"
  type    = "A"
  ttl     = "300"
  records = ["${aws_eip.lb.public_ip}"]
}
```

Note, that you can only read output variables from remote states. You cannot access resources directly, as terraform treats other states/modules as black boxes.

**Update**

As mentioned in the comments, `terraform_remote_state` is a simple way to share explicitly published variables across multiple states. However, it comes with 2 issues:

1. Close coupling between code components, i.e., producer of the variable cannot change easily.
2. It can only be used by terraform, i.e., you cannot easily share those variables across different layers. Configuration tools such as Ansible cannot use `.tfstate` natively without some additional custom plugin/wrapper.

The recommended HashiCorp way is to use a central config store such as Consul. It comes with more benefits:

1. Consumer is decoupled from the variable producer.
2. Explicit publishing of variables (like in `terraform_remote_state`).
3. Can be used by other tools.

A more detailed explanation can be found [here](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-terraform-remote-state-over-common-data-filters/2376/2).

Comment: I really like this answer. I did not know about remote state. Very useful.

Comment: Would be really nice to know how to manage multiple backends, because you need to specify them. Imagine you have 5 repos and 5 states, imagine you need outputs for all of the states in all 5 repos. Now you'll be copying backend.tf to each repo? Really wonder how to handle this.

Comment: Working with `terraform_remote_state` can be tedious. As @holms points out it leads to close coupling between multiple code components. I think this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57378189/using-terraform-remote-state-over-common-data-filters) targets that issue.

Summary: the official HashiCorp way is to use a config store such as consul. It gives you decoupling, explicit publishing and compatibility with other tools.

Answer (score 2):

An approach I've used in the past is to have a single repo for all of the Infrastructure.

An alternative is to have 2 separate tf configurations, each using [remote state](https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/remote.html). Config 1 can use output variables to store any arns/ids as necessary.

Config 2 can then have a [remote_state data source](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/terraform/d/remote_state.html) to query for the relevant arns/ids.

E.g.

```
# Declare remote state
data "terraform_remote_state" "network" {
  backend = "s3"
  config {
    bucket = "my-terraform-state"
    key    = "network/terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-1"
  }
}
```

You can then use output values using standard interpolation syntax 
`${data.terraform_remote_state.network.some_id}`

Comment: I didn't know about remote state, thanks! I have decided not to manage terraform from multiple repos and just have a single repo to manage my infrastructure like you have done in the past.

Comment: I found that to be a clear approach. You can still 'chunk' your entire configuration up into separate configurations within the same rep. For example split by region (Europe, US etc) or environment (dev, prod etc)

Comment: I have not had a need for separate regions yet. If I do I will probably have separate state files for them. I am using terraform workspaces for managing separate state for different environments. I have not run a production environment yet by when I do I will use completely separate state files (no workspaces) and deploy to a separate aws account to prevent any accidents