# Using terraform_remote_state over common data filters

Tags: terraform

I would like to understand when it is recommended to use `terraform_remote_state` over common data filter approaches.

I see cases like images, which are not managed by another terraform state in which case the obvious (and only) choice are data filters. 
However, in most cases I could choose between `terraform_remote_state` and other data filters. I could not find an official recommendation on that matter.

Let's take an example
(The following code does not run as is and is simplified to only show the main idea):

Let us assume we have a central component with its own state/workspace

**vault/main.tf:**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tfstates"
    container_name       = "tfstates"
    key                  = "vault/all.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "openstack" {
  version     = "1.19"
  cloud       = "openstack"
}

resource "openstack_networking_subnetpool_v2" "vault" {
  name              = "vault"
  prefixes          = ["10.1.0.0/16"]
  min_prefixlen     = 24
  default_prefixlen = 24
}

resource "openstack_networking_network_v2" "vault" {
  name           = "vault"
}

resource "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "vault" {
  name            = "vault"
  network_id      = openstack_networking_network_v2.vault.id
  subnetpool_id   = openstack_networking_subnetpool_v2.vault.id
}

// Make cidr available for terraform_remote_state approach
output "cidr" {
  value = openstack_networking_subnet_v2.vault.cidr
}

....
```

---

### Option 1: Whitelist vault cidr in another tf workspace with data filters

**postgres/main.tf:**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tfstates"
    container_name       = "tfstates"
    key                  = "postgres/all.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "openstack" {
  version     = "1.19"
  cloud       = "openstack"
}

data "openstack_identity_project_v3" "vault" {
  // assuming vault is setup in its own project
  name = "vault"
}

data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "vault" {
  name      = "vault"
  tenant_id = data.openstack_identity_project_v3.vault.id
}

data "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "vault" {
  name      = "vault"
  tenant_id = data.openstack_identity_project_v3.vault.id
}

resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_v2" "postgres" {
  name        = "postgres"
  description = "Allow vault connection"
}

resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_rule_v2" "allow-vault" {
  direction         = "ingress"
  ethertype         = "IPv4"
  security_group_id = openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.postgres.id
  remote_ip_prefix  = data.openstack_networking_subnet_v2.vault.cidr 
}
```

---

### Option 2: Whitelist vault cidr in another tf workspace with terraform_remote_state

**postgres/main.tf:**

```
terraform {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tfstates"
    container_name       = "tfstates"
    key                  = "postgres/all.tfstate"
  }
}

provider "openstack" {
  version     = "1.19"
  cloud       = "openstack"
}

data "terraform_remote_state" "vault" {
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "tfstates"
    container_name       = "tfstates"
    key                  = "vault/all.tfstate"
  }
}

resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_v2" "postgres" {
  name        = "postgres"
  description = "Allow vault connection"
}

resource "openstack_networking_secgroup_rule_v2" "allow-vault" {
  direction         = "ingress"
  ethertype         = "IPv4"
  security_group_id = openstack_networking_secgroup_v2.postgres.id
  remote_ip_prefix  = data.terraform_remote_state.vault.cidr 
}
```

Personally, I prefer `terraform_remote_state` because it feels less ambiguous and more declarative from a module perspective (i.e., you consciously declare output variables that should be used by other workspaces). However, I'm interested if there are solid reasons against it or if there are some best practices I'm not aware of.

Is there an officially recommended way for scenarios like that?

Comment: Reaching out to the hashicorp community directly: https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-terraform-remote-state-over-common-data-filters/2376

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@martin-atkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/281848) gave a great [answer](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-terraform-remote-state-over-common-data-filters/2376/2) in the HashiCorp discussion forum.

However, he did not respond on this thread, so I am summarizing with my own words the gist for the sake of completion.

---

The adequate HashiCorp way would be a third option: write parameters to a configuration store such as Consul.

This gives multiple benefits:

1. You are in control of what you expose to other tools
   (benefit of question's Option 2: explicit publishing)
2. You do not have close coupling between Terraform workspaces (benefit of question's Option 1: decoupling). I.e., the variable producer is decoupled from the variable consumer.
3. Other tools, including Terraform itself are able to use the values later on.

---

I recommend to read the [original answer](https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/using-terraform-remote-state-over-common-data-filters/2376/2) as it has more depth.