# What is the optimal way to structure your terraform code (or any IaC) when working with microservices?

Tags: architecture, terraform, microservices, infrastructure, infrastructure-as-code

I'd like to understand what is the recommended way to structure a Terraform project when working with microservices. Let's suppose that I have a web client, a mobile app and a backend. I'm using the AWS infrastructure with Terraform. With this in mind, I want to achieve the following:

1. I want my components (clients and services) to be independent
2. I want my CI/CD pipeline to recognise the dependencies between my components (e.g. when I update my backend code, I want it to be deployed)
3. I want my infrastructure code to be centralized (i.e. single state, cross-service variables such as domain name, etc)

It appears that there are a few ways to achieve this:

1. Monorepo: create a git repo for your project then underneath that, create a directory for your individual components and your infra. This may work for small projects, but I don't think it scales well (some future services may live in separate repositories and may interact with multiple other services not owned by your team). Nonetheless, for personal hobby projects it may work well -- I'm curious to hear what you all think about that. [Here](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/terraform-microservices-example) is an example of such setup
2. Using a remote state as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48167519/3236215). In this setup, each component (backend, frontend, etc) would have their own terraform file and a state, we would then import and reference the state of one in the other. This solution does not sound great to me because it creates coupling and your infra code is all over the place (in each service plus you'd probably need a centralized infra repo for things like VPCs etc). I think it also makes it harder to set up your CI/CD (e.g. if I push changes in my backend repo, I may also want to trigger terraform plan/apply in another centralized infra repo).

I could be missing something, but I'm surprised that this problem isn't commonly addressed when it seems like the most common use case for terraform or any IaC solution. I don't have any experience with IaC professionally and I'd appreciate any feedback or thoughts

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this exact issue in my daily job (on quite a big scale) and indeed, it's quite challenging to get it right, mostly because it depends on a number of factors:

- What's the prediction of the infra code change in the future? Usually the infra code gets built once, and then only minor updates are added along the way. Is it going to be a frequent operation or not really?
- How many people are going to update the infra code over time? Do they need to check-out many repos or a single one?
- How many teams are going to own those repos? There will be one team or many?

Those are just a few thoughts, but I'm sure there can be other aspects that should be considered.

Now from my experience, this is what I can share (hopefully useful):

- If the infra code complexity is not projected to be huge, you can start with a dedicated repo that contains all the terraform code. I used that for years and it works even if the infrastructure components is owned by multiple teams. It's not ideal, but it's a working solution.
- Splitting the code into each repository can/should be done when the mono-repo gets too big and hard to manage. This will add coupling between the new mono-repo (because you may still need some global infra components, like VPCs or subnets), and the code in each repo. However, in this way you're going to have all the code of a component in a single repo, which is useful for debugging, migrating the service on a different cloud provider (maybe).

Initially I used the first approach and then progressively transitioned to the second one (for new services being deployed). In both cases, the infra code was updated only once (when the service was deployed) and remained untouched afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I've started avidly working with terraform in ~2017 & it has taken me a few years to get to where I am now with terraform modules & structures:

- Each terraform module has it's repo & is versioned (not it's own
  state file though).
- Each terraform module is 100% re-usable by ensuring every
  parameter is a variable.
- Each terraform module is 100% re-usable by ensuring 1:1
  module:resource. No other modules are called within these modules.

Examples;

1 terraform module for AWS Load Balancer

1 terraform module for AWS Auto Scaling Group

(or I use a pre-defined HashiCorp module).

- Root Modules are used to tie all the Resource Modules above and
  that is where the terraform plan is applied. It's made it very
  easy for me to copy and past root modules as templates for other
  stacks and just change variables.
- I use terraform cloud to manage & import all the terraform modules as well as my workspaces (root modules). This helps with centralization. Within Terraform Cloud it's very easy to see where a workspace (root module / plan) has failed and the last time it was run. Alarms can be added via web hooks making infra mgmt more tangible.
- With the above set-up my CI/CD pipeline uses a terraform cloud token to trigger any related infra set up or refresh.
- For any server related setup (such as AWS EC2 Instances), code is automatically deployed via bootstraps aka user-data when a new EC2 is deployed.
- Be sure to use consistent naming conventions!

I've found the above approach to really help with managing micro-services and any kind of cloud infra, whether it's serverless or server based.